# Server specific usernames for each SSH connection in Chef with Knife

Tags: ssh, chef, configuration, knife

To set a default user for each ssh connection, I would normally adjust my `.ssh/config` file to

`Host *.server1.com

User joe`

Host *.server2.com
User mike

I am now using Chef.  [The knife tool does not read from .ssh/config](http://tech.picklive.com/2011/11/15/knife-ssh-config-options.html).  So how can I set default usernames based on host?

One solution I do NOT want is to create a default "chef" user with full admin rights on every server and then use that user for batch server processes.  There are many reasons I am hoping for a more optimal answer.

Answer (score 0):

So this feature doesn't exist yet in Chef - I'd encourage you to upvote and watch the ticket over here: https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-4538

Potentially, you could grab the code change, and use it as a knife plugin, but that might be a little more monkeypatching code you'd want to do. :)